# Does any Addin Required for Autoamting a PDF application using UFT

Tags: pdf, qtp, hp-uft, qtplugin

There is a PDF application which have listbox,textbox,checkbox          etc ,i  need  to automate using HP-UFT ,does it need any plugin ,since when i tried a piece of code it a run time error that "active x is unable to create the object "even though active x addin is checked on or off

Answer (score 0):

APTT - Adobe Pdf Test Toolkit

Like any other objects that are added in your Object repository, you would wish that there was a plug-in for adobe too. Here is the solution to that
Download ADOBE APTT plugin.
If you install ADOBE APTT plugin, QTP starts identifying the objects in PDF like any other object.
This can be downloaded from: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/aptt/